# How to make table cells editable

Tags: java, javafx

people! Can you help me with this case: I want to create table with `String` objects and possibility to edit it;

I have method to create tableview, input Observable list with lists of Strings - `ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> observableList`

Code:

```
private TableView createTable(ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> observableList){
    TableView tableView = new TableView();

    VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

    for(int i = 0; i < observableList.get(0).size(); i++){
        TableColumn tableColumn;

        if(i == 0){
            tableColumn = new TableColumn();
        }else {
            tableColumn = new TableColumn("S" + i);
        }

        int finalI = i;
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(finalI).toString());
            }
        });
        tableColumn.setSortable(false);
        tableColumn.setReorderable(false);
        tableColumn.setEditable(true);

        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
    }

    tableView.setItems(observableList);
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    return tableView;
}
```

Comment: you need a cell that supports editing (f.i. TextFieldTableCell)